# VS2019 MSTest V2 not showing discovered unit tests in Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

Updated to MSTest.TestFramework and TestAdapter V2 via NuGet Package Manager.  Now Test Explorer does not show any of the discovered unit tests.  It does work fine in version 1.4.  They are all .net Framework tests.

The Tests output says:

```
[9/30/2019 11:05:50.280 AM Informational] ---------- Discovery started ----------
[9/30/2019 11:06:07.342 AM Informational] ========== Discovery finished: 388 tests found (0:00:17.0597599) ==========
[9/30/2019 11:06:07.343 AM Informational] No tests found to run.
```

and Test Explorer is empty:
[image]

Comment: delete `bin` and `obj` folder then rebuild test project

Comment: already tried that, restarted vs, etc.

Comment: Did you remove the references to the previous version?

Comment: I had a similar issue with v2 when it was recently released and that was one of my issues. ended up removing older references removing and then re-adding the new one and  then it started seeing them.

Comment: I added a reference to the old framework (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework) and gave it an alias in the properties in order to avoid a collision of namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing (migrating from MSTest to MSTestV2 by NuGet and I deleted the old reference which was causing conflicts) and I had exactly the same issue of empty Test Explorer window.

In my case the solution was to clear the cache by removing everything from folder: %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions while restarting VS. All tests appeared back again.

Hope it helps.